# Unable to Download Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mern, react-fullstack

```
⚠ Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc, but an error occurred: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\newWeb\nextapp1\node_modules\@next\swc-win32-ia32-msvc\next-swc.win32-ia32-msvc.node
 ⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for win32/ia32, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc
```

this error is being given i have checked if the above msvc file exists or not also, even tried getting the entire folder whitelisted from the windows antiVirus(i previously had one) and still now working

Comment: Where did you download it from?  Di you check is authentic?

Comment: I have copied the link from nextJs official documentation